# Spring Web streaming endpoint (using ResponseBodyEmitter) configured with GSON gets closed after one response object is written

Tags: java, spring, gson

I have an endpoint that's leveraging Spring's `ResponseBodyEmitter` feature to stream a response back to the client.  Let's suppose the endpoint signature looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseBodyEmitter streamQuotes(@RequestParam("symbols") String symbolList);
```

The application running this is a Spring boot web application.  By default, the application uses Jackson to serialize response objects, which get written to the response output stream as chunks of JSON.

This all works fine.  I'm able to call this endpoint and the response is a stream of data coming back over a period of time.  This is the behavior that I expect.

The problem I'm having is when I switch out Jackson and replace it with GSON, as follows:

```
@Bean
public GsonHttpMessageConverter getGsonHttpMessageConverter() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .create();

    GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    gsonConverter.setGson(gson);
    return gsonConverter;
}
```

If I make a request to the same endpoint with GSON as the message converter, I receive only the first data object written to the stream.  At this point, the connection is closed and the server returns 200/OK.  It seems like something in the GSON message converter is closing the output stream.

What do I need to change in my Spring/GSON configuration to make this work in the same manner that Jackson does (stream is left open and data is written to it over time)?

Comment: Do you have malformed JSON responses with Gson? If the output is closed prematurely, I think, it must be detected somehow -- the converter `writeInternal` method may be the cause. I recently implemented a Gson-converter along with some custom serializers that can respond with `Stream<T>` in controllers, but it does not appear to be what you need since it does not use `ResponseBodyEmitter`. I abandoned the standard Gson converter implementation due to the premature close on the read.